# Haskell ForkIO limit number of threads to certain value

Tags: haskell, fork

Seems like ForkIO creates as many threads as there are cores in the Haskell program I work with

```
-- | Fork a thread in checker monad.
fork :: Checker a b () -> Checker a b ()
fork act = do
  s0 <- get
  void $ liftIO $ forkIO (curTGroup s0) $ evalChecker act s0

occurs :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int
occurs x = length . filter (x==)
```

https://github.com/PLSysSec/sys/blob/821c4d7cf924e68838c128cbe824be46c9955416/src/Static/Check.hs#L73

New to Haskel ForkIO, I wanted to set the thread amount using setNumCapabilities.

Tried adding

```
let setNumCapabilities = 1
```

Haskell made a warning about unused var and this didn't make any effect.

How to do it properly?

Comment: The usual first step is to say `-rtsopts` when compiling/linking, and then pass `+RTS -N however-many -RTS` when running your program. (You can skip the `-RTS` if you don't want any more arguments after that.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**`setNumCapabilities :: Int -> IO ()`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Control-Concurrent.html#v:setNumCapabilities) is a *function*. You thus use it in your code with:

```
import Control.Concurrent(setNumCapabilities)

fork :: Checker a b () -> Checker a b ()
fork act = do
  s0 <- get
  void $ liftIO $ do
    setNumCapabilities 1
    forkIO (curTGroup s0) $ evalChecker act s0
```

or somewhere else, for example in the `main` function.